# a weird attribute on every html tag

Tags: plugins, jquery, actions, customization

me and my friend working on a Wordpress site but we see it differently on our machines,

He sees a weird attribute wfd-id="" on every html tag in google console when he inspect it,
also I loaded JQuery in my page successfully but he cant see it

The DOM load differently on our machines, whats the problem

We reloaded, refreshed, cleared cache and every possible method we could think of

We cant even detect the source of the problem

Comment: Is it definitely something on the site, and not e.g. [a Chrome plugin modifying the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22121018/243245)? Or his editor if he sees this after working on a page? Can he reproduce it on a different browser, or logging in as himself on your computer? Can you check the raw HTML responses in his browser to see if the tags are there?

Comment: thanks we are testing in incognito mode right now without any plugin to see the result

Comment: Even in incognito mode, chrome extensions can still be active. Can you make sure they're all deactivated, try a different browser, or download the page using curl or wget? As for jQuery, does inspection of the source show the page trying to load it anywhere? If so, are there console error messages about it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, a weird attribute wfd-id="" on every element. For me it was kaspersky password manager chrome extension, after deactivate it, everything backs to normal again, the weird attribute as gone. Hope it helps someone.